# how to create a plugin for outlook to like zoom meet for outlook

Tags: plugins, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

How can we create a plugin like zoom in the outlook, commands button should appear in the top ribbon-like zoom.

[image]

I have used the office [yo add-in generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) but that seems not having option to create a top ribbon for outlook.

Answer (score 0):

For Web Add-ins Adding buttons to the Calendar View in the Explorer Frame is not supported. Buttons can only be added to existing items, when the item is opened in a separate window. To get buttons in the explorer, you will need to explore a COM Add-in Model.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

These buttons are coming from a COM add-in. The web add-ins doesn't provide such feature yet. So, if you want to get such functionality in Outlook for desktop you need to develop a VSTO add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=Create%20the%20project,-To%20create%20a&text=On%20the%20File%20menu%2C%20point,Outlook%20VSTO%20Add%2Din%20project.) for more information.

The [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019) article explains how to create a custom tab and then add and position controls on it.